# Piping and If statement with multiple outputs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, pipe

What am I missing here...

```
df <- data.frame("sn" = 1:3, "age" = c(21,15, 18), "name" = c("John","Dora", "Lynn"))

df %>% if (df$age >= 18){
  df$drive <- "yes"
  df$vote <- "yes"
}

Error in if (.) df$age >= 18 else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

...in trying to make this dataframe?

```
  sn age name drive vote
1  1  21 John   yes  yes
2  2  15 Dora    no   no
3  3  21 Lynn   yes  yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `ifelse` or `case_when` as these are vectorized while `if/else` is not i.e. it expects a vector of length 1 as logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(drive = case_when(age >=18 ~ "yes", TRUE ~"no"),
             vote = drive)
```

In `base R`, we can do

```
df[c('drive', 'vote')] <- 'no'
df[df$agge >=18, c('drive', 'vote')] <- 'yes'
```

Comment: so to evaluate two cases I would add %>% mutate(vote = case_when(age >=18 ~ "yes", TRUE ~"no"))

Comment: @seansteele if it the same, then you can just use `vote = drive` (based on your condition, both are same)

Answer (score 0):

We can compare `age` with 18 and assign `"yes"`, `"no"` values based on that. Since the age for driving and voting is the same we can use the same values for `vote` as well.

```
df$drive <- c('no', 'yes')[(df$age >= 18) + 1]
df$vote <- df$drive
df

#  sn age name drive vote
#1  1  21 John   yes  yes
#2  2  15 Dora    no   no
#3  3  18 Lynn   yes  yes
```

We can also use `ifelse`/`if_else` to get output here but it would be slower than the above approach.